# Is this parametrization of the intersection of two surfaces correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $C$ denote the curve of intersection of the two given surfaces:

$x+y=2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=2(x+y)$.

find a parametrization to $C$.

Here's my solution attempt:

Take a parameter $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and set $y=t$. Hence it follows that:

$x=2-t$ and that

$4-4t +2t^2+z^2=4$ $\implies$ $z^2=4t-2t^2$.

Therefore our parametrization is $\gamma(t)=(2-t, t ,\sqrt{4t-2t^2})$.

Is it correct? what happens with the negative values of z?

Comment: Your parametrization does not "hit" the entire curve of intersection. (Separately, your formula only makes sense for $0 \leq t \leq 2$.) Just asking: Do you know (geometrically) what the intersection curve is?

Comment: No, i do not kow what this curve actually is. Why did you argue that this parametrization doesn't hit the entire curve? thanks.

Comment: Thiking a little bit, i guess that the intersection is a circunferece, since $x^2+y^2+z^2=2(x+y)$ is a sphere and $x+y=2$ is a plane.

Comment: Precisely. And your curve traces a semicircle. :)

Comment: So, the final response would be separate the curve of intersection into two parts:

$\gamma_1(t)$ for z positive, and $\gamma_2(t)$ for z negative. The range of t would still be the same $t\in[0,2]$.

Right?

Comment: Parametrizing by two semicircles is one possibility. Another would be to use trig functions, see for example the accepted answer to [Parametrization for intersection of sphere and plane](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305894) (the sphere differs from yours, but by chance the intersection curve is identical).